# Not able to show icon with text using appcompat lib

Tags: android, menuitem, android-appcompat

I am trying to show icon with text using appcompat lib but i m not able to do it.

Either it shows icon or just text in overflow menu if i remove icon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_next"
        android:title="Next"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_cab_done_holo_dark"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
</menu>
```

help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: make sure your activity `extends ActionBarActivity`. I tried your xml. It display icon with text in mobile landscape mode but not in portrait. @Hitendra

Comment: @Pooja, I use ActionBarActivity. I haven't tried it with landscape mode as i don't need it.

Comment: Your code working fine in Nexus 7 tablet(portrait mode). I think it is issue regarding mobile portrait mode as there is not much space available.

Comment: Yes, I read somewhere that width should be atleast 480dp.

Answer (score 0):

You can create actions with text in 2 ways:

1- From XML:

```
<item android:id="@id/resource_name"
      android:title="text"
      android:icon="@drawable/drawable_resource_name"
      android:showAsAction="withText" />
```

2- Programmatically:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, ID, POSITION, TEXT);
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.drawable_resource_name);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have tried using android:showAction with multiple values but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck at this problem. use this code, working fine for me.

```html
@Override
 public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
  if (featureId == Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR && menu != null) {
   if (menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder")) {
    try {
     Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
       "setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
     m.setAccessible(true);
     m.invoke(menu, true);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
     Log.d("DEBUG", "onMenuOpened", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
   }
  }
  return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
 }
```

And menu.xml is like

```html
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_logout"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_rate"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_rate"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:title="RATE US"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:orderInCategory="102"
        android:title="SHARE APP"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Try it and let me know